# Socket.IO as a transparent proxy for PHPDaemon WebScoket

Tags: php, node.js, proxy, websocket, socket.io

I have a WebSocket server written by another person on PHPDaemon. Members there are connected, log in, and start getting messages by ws protocol. But users of older browsers and IE below 10 remain behind. And it would be greate to add something like transparent cross-browser proxy client for older browsers without breaking current architecture of websocket server. Can I somehow implement that with socket.io or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use engine.io (previously socket.io) for that. It will take care of selecting the adequate transport for you.

There are really plenty of examples & tutorials on the web on how to use it. It is pretty straight forward.

https://github.com/automattic/engine.io